# Merge CSV files in Python: only keep 1 column of each file and name the columns with original file names

Tags: python, csv, join, merge, stock

I have 7 csv files of 7 stocks. Each file shares the same format, of columns and rows.

I have applied different ways to merge these files into 1 dataframe but still don't succeed (loop, using glob, etc). I want to keep the "Date" column as the index for the dataframe, and the "High" column of each file next to each other. Then the "High" columns are renamed based on the stock names.

```
import pandas as pd
FDX = pd.read_csv("../Data/FDX.csv")
GOOGL = pd.read_csv("../Data/GOOGL.csv")
IBM = pd.read_csv("../Data/IBM.csv")
KO = pd.read_csv("../Data/KO.csv")
MS = pd.read_csv("../Data/MS.csv")
NOK = pd.read_csv("../Data/NOK.csv")
XOM = pd.read_csv("../Data/XOM.csv")

stocks = pd.DataFrame({"FDX": FDX["High"],
                       "GOOGL": GOOGL["High"],
                       "IBM": IBM["High"],
                       "KO": KO["High"],
                       "MS": MS["High"],
                       "NOK": NOK["High"],
                       "XOM": XOM["High"]
                       })
stocks.head()
```

The codes I wrote has errors. In there anyway to do it?
Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Please before you post look at the formatted version of your post below the edit box. Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code plus desired output plus clear specification & explanation. Please show what relevant queries you can do & explain re the first place you are stuck. Dumps of requirements are not on-topic questions.

Answer (score 0):

If they all have the same date range this would work.

```
MergeList = [[GOOGL,'GOOGL'],[IBM,'IBM'],[KO,'KO'],[MS,'MS'],[NOK,'NOK'],[XOM,'XOM']]

NewList = []

for df_t,col_name in MergeList:
    df_t = df_t[['Date','High']]
    df_t.columns = ['Date',col_name]
    NewList.append(df_t)

Merge = FDX

for df_t in NewList:
    Merge = pd.merge(Merge,df_t,on='Date')
```

Comment: Thank you but it's not working. The error is KeyError: "['Date' 'High'] not in index"

Comment: You need to make sure that that is the name of the column you want (this is case sensitive), you didn't provide actual data, so I took a guess as to the names of the columns.Look at the dataframes you have created (GOOGL, IBM, etc...)